# How do I count how many times a value appears in a MySQL column?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table called Reports, and in it is a column called Status. This is set to either Open, Pending, or Closed. I need to be able to count how many reports are set to Open, Closed, and Pending respectively. I also need to put these numbers into individual variables for use in a graph.

I use PDO on the site and am easily able to add, edit, and retrieve data but I can't for the life of me get this to work. I find PDO very confusing and difficult to learn since everyone seems to use completely different formatting, syntax, and variable names in all the examples I can find online. I have no idea if I'm even on the right track with this. Here's what I've come up with so far;

```
try {
$DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);
$DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT status, COUNT(*) FROM reports GROUP BY status");
$result = $STH->fetch();
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

I don't get any errors or anything. How can I even troubleshoot this?

As a bit of an extra feature, I'd like to be able to only count the values of entries submitted between certain dates. I have a date column already in the database.

Am I on the right track? Completely off? I can make this work no problem with straight MySQL queries but not with PDO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've missed the `execute()` command? You may also want to use `fetchAll` instead of `fetch` to get everything.

```
try {
    $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);
    $DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT status, COUNT(*) AS count FROM reports WHERE date_field BETWEEN :start_date AND :end_date GROUP BY status");
    $STH->execute(array(':start_date' => $start_date_variable, ':end_date' => $end_date_variable));


    $rows = $STH->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        echo $row['status'] . " = " . $row['count'];
    }

}catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Think you're not actually running the query currently? Haven't used PDO for a while so may be wrong but give it a try..

Comment: I tried this and something happened, though not sure what. Here's the result; array(2) { ["status"]=> string(6) "Closed" ["COUNT(*)"]=> string(2) "23" } array(2) { ["status"]=> string(4) "Open" ["COUNT(*)"]=> string(1) "1" } array(2) { ["status"]=> string(7) "Pending" ["COUNT(*)"]=> string(1) "3" } array(2) { ["status"]=> string(7) "Removed" ["COUNT(*)"]=> string(2) "10" }

Comment: That's your results :) I updated my answer (inside the foreach) to format the results nicer. I just used `var_dump()` to throw everything to the screen before.

Comment: I've also updated the query to include your question about dates. Think that'd work. Don't know if you want variable dates?

Comment: Thanks! This really helped me a lot. I would like variable dates, is that as simple as plugging variables in where you have the dates written?

Comment: Updated again with how to use prepared statements for the start/end date. These will protect against SQL injection etc. If you just stuck the variables in, you wouldn't be protected.

Comment: Thanks again for the help. I've been trying to figure this out for several days now!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need something to this effect:

```
SELECT sum(
    IF (
            COALESCE (status, '') = 'Open',
            1,
            0
        )
    ) AS total_open,
    sum(

        IF (
            COALESCE (status, '') = 'Closed',
            1,
            0
        )
    ) AS total_closed,
    sum(

        IF (
            COALESCE(status, '') = 'Pending ',
            1,
            0
        )
    ) AS total_pending
FROM reports
```

This should give you the total number of each in 3 different columns that you can use for your graph.